# How to set log4net's log file location in autofac?

Tags: log4net

I am now adding controller log by following this post: [Using Autofac to inject log4net into controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885477/using-autofac-to-inject-log4net-into-controller)

After doing that, I can get my application run correctly. Below are the details:

LogInjectionModule here:

```
public class LogInjectionModule:Module
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing += OnComponentPreparing;
    }

    static void OnComponentPreparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = e.Component.Activator.LimitType;
        e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(new[] 
        { 
            new ResolvedParameter((p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof(ILog), (p, i) => LogManager.GetLogger(t)) 
        });
    }
}
```

DependencyRegister here:

```
private void RegisterDependency()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

        builder.RegisterType<BookContext>().As<IDbContext>().SingleInstance().PreserveExistingDefaults();
        builder.RegisterType<ManagerRepository>().As<IManager>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<BookLendRepository>().As<IBookLend>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<BookPlaceRepository>().As<IBookPlace>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<BookRepository>().As<IBook>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<BookTypeRepository>().As<IBookType>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<StudentRepository>().As<IStudent>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

        builder.RegisterType<ManagerService>().As<IManagerService>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

        builder.RegisterModule(new LogInjectionModule());

        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

    }
```

MyController here:

```
public HomeController(
         IManagerService managerService
        ,ILog logger
        )
    {
        this.managerService = managerService;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    private readonly IManagerService managerService;
    private readonly ILog logger;

    public ActionResult Index(Manager manager)
    {
        logger.Info("test");
        return View();
    }
```

And when I debug to  logger.Info("test") , I can get the log instance. But the problem is , where is the log file's location? is there any config  for the integrated log4net that I can decide where to put the log file?

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't related to Autofac. Log4net is a standalone library. You can read more about log4net on its [homepage](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) and how to configure it [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html).